# I changed my name on Google+ but in the search results still show my old name

Tags: google-search, search-engines, google+

I edited my name on Google+, by substituting my real name with a nickname.

If I enter my real name in the Google search bar (and on other search engines as well), I get links to my Google+ profile. In the search results page I see my real name (the old one), whereas when I click on the link and get the page on Google+, there is the new (nick)name.

What am I suppose to do to hide my old name from search results?

Comment: How long since you mad the change?

Comment: one month ago more or less

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may take up to 3 months for those changes to reflect in Google search results, If your Profile is worthy and has a lot of visitors then changes can be seen within a short period of time, otherwise, it may take longer than expected.

Personal Experience, Blogger since 2012.